# Flickering in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to visualize Baxter Robot while providing joint trajectory in rviz. I am calling rviz from following launch file-

```
<launch>
    <arg name="file" default="$(find kinematics_animation)/demos/baxter/joint_states.csv" />
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py
    --inorder $(find baxter_description)/urdf/baxter.urdf.xacro"/>
    <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"/>
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" respawn="false" name="rviz"
      args="-d $(find kinematics_animation)/demos/baxter/baxter_rviz_config.rviz" />
    <node pkg="kinematics_animation" type="player.py" name="baxter_animation">
        <param name="file" value="$(arg file)" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

Below is the snippet from python file-

```
def __init__(self):
    freq = 50
    self.rate = 1.0

    rospy.loginfo("Publishing frequency = "+str(freq))
    fname = rospy.get_param("~file", None)
    if fname is None:
        rospy.logerr("Must provide private param '~file'")
        rospy.signal_shutdown("No CSV file provided")
    else:
        rospy.loginfo("Animation file = "+fname)
    rospy.loginfo("Time scaling = " + str(self.rate))
    # load data:
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        fline = f.readline()
    self.names = fline.rstrip('\r\n').split(',')
    self.names = self.names[1:]
    self.dat = np.loadtxt(fname, skiprows=1, delimiter=',')
    self._fint = interp1d(1/float(self.rate)*self.dat[:,0], self.dat[:,1:], kind='linear', axis=0)
    self.base_time = rospy.Time.now()
    # create publisher:
    self.state_pub = rospy.Publisher("joint_states", JointState, latch=True, queue_size=3)
    # create timer:
    self.pbtimer = rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1/float(freq)), self.timercb)
    return

def timercb(self, time_dat):
    t = (rospy.Time.now() - self.base_time).to_sec()
    try :
        q = self._fint(t)
    except ValueError:
        q = self._fint.y[-1]
        if (t - self._fint.x[-1]) > 2.0:
            rospy.loginfo("Resetting animation!")
            self.base_time = rospy.Time.now()
    js = JointState(name=self.names, position=q)
    js.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    self.state_pub.publish(js)
    return
```

The problem is that after calling the launch file, rvis starts flickering the Baxter arms. It feels to me that everytime, arms are going back to home position. How can I resolve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235375/flickering-in-rviz/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2016-05-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot have two nodes publishing to the JointStates topic for the same set of joints at the same time. In your launch file you have

```
<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
```

and you start your own node, that also publishes joint states. So the `robot_state_publisher` now receives joint states telling it that the joints are at their default joint position (which is probably 0, published by the `joint_state_publisher`) and the ones your `kinematics_animation` node is publishing. As a result, it publishes transforms for the '0 position' and the other positions after each other in rapid succession, resulting in what you describe as a flicker.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2016-05-27**:
Oh. my mistake. Sorry. I removed the above suggested line from launch file. Animation is smooth. However, I don't see Baxter Head, Display etc. Please see the attached screenshot of rviz [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51884474/rviz.png). It is not able to find out various transformations

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-27**:
Yes, that is how things work. You'll have to have something that provides either the joint states or the TF frames. I suggest you [read up](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher) on some of the [involved packages](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-27**:
If you want to display trajectories for only certain sets of joints, I suggest using something like [moveit_visual_tools](https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_visual_tools) by Dave Coleman.

JointStates are really only for reporting the state of joints, nothing else.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-27**:
Alternatively you should publish JointStates for all joints of Baxter, but keep the ones you don't want to change at their defaults (which could be 0).

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2016-05-27**:
Really appreciate your efforts. Thanks a lot. I want to move both the arms as decribed in input csv file, which contains joint angle for all joints. It is working but I can't see Baxter head. I am attaching screenshot please see https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51884474/rviz.png

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-27**:
Have you read the pages I linked to? I can't really tell you anything more than I already wrote in the comments.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2019-10-17**:
I encountered flickering in rviz when publishing to a marker_array topic from two different publishers (I assumed unique namespace id combinations would be sufficient), changed to two separate topics and now it looks good.